# ORACLE %TYPE replacement in SNOWFLAKE

Tags: javascript, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create or replace FUNCTION Func (val_cd   in  owner.dom_val.val%TYPE,
                                 col_val  in  owner.ld_leg.leg_id%type,
                                 col_name in  varchar2)
```

Do we have any similar thing for this %type in Snowflake? I tried with `TypeOf(<col_name>)` but it is not working properly.

Comment: When you say *"it is not working properly"* what do you mean? Do you get an error? If so, please include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_typeof.html

the regular typeof is for variant values which is probably why it's not cooperating with your usecase

still, it has limitations (ie can't be used in create statements which you can do with oracle)

Answer (score 0):

%TYPE is used to declare variables that will refer to the data type of a column in the referenced table or from a previously declared variable

This is currently not supported for creating the objects.

The explicitly supported data types are provided in the below link
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types.html

You could query the data type of an expression using the system_typeof function

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_typeof.html